# Python Pandas DF - Group column with corresponding frequency count of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a data frame in python. In it I have one column with different people and another column with different products they bought. 
I try to create a summary for each person how much they bought of each product. Therefore, I tried to group by persons and products and count, but somehow I'm running into trouble.

Find in the following a small toy example.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create toy data frame
A = [0,0,1,2,2,2,0]
B = ['Person1','Person1','Person1','Person1','Person2','Person2','Person 2']
df = pd.DataFrame([A,B]).transpose()
df.columns = ['cat', 'per']

# Desired Output

          Cat0    Cat1    Cat2
Person 1     2       1       1 
Person 2     1       0       2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first add string `cat` to values, but you need cast `int` to `str` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html). Then use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) and last [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`):

```
import pandas as pd

# Create toy data frame
A = [0,0,1,2,2,2,0]
B = ['Person1','Person1','Person1','Person1','Person2','Person2','Person2']
df = pd.DataFrame([A,B]).transpose()
df.columns = ['cat', 'per']

print (df)
  cat      per
0   0  Person1
1   0  Person1
2   1  Person1
3   2  Person1
4   2  Person2
5   2  Person2
6   0  Person2

df['cat'] = 'cat' + df.cat.astype(str)
df = df.pivot_table(index='per', columns='cat', aggfunc=len,fill_value=0)

df = df.rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
#if use older pandas as 0.18.0
#df.columns.name= None
#df.index.name= None

print (df)
         cat0  cat1  cat2
Person1     2     1     1
Person2     1     0     2
```